# How to access the data-eid value from the main Google Calendar page

Tags: javascript, google-calendar-api

I am trying to figure out how to access the data-eid for a given Google Calendar event directly from the main view of the Calendar, not from the resulting event edit page that appears when an event is clicked. Each event title is clickable and appears to have a unique div class in the format of "evt-lk ca-elp5"

[image]

which, when clicked, runs some minified JS functions and renders the edit page, which *does* contain the data-eid both in the page URL and within a class inside "coverinner".

[image]

Now, the question is, can the data-eid be determined without clicking on the event link to go to the edit page?  I have tried parsing through the minified JS code from the calendar page, and attaching to the click event in Chrome's debugger, and haven't had much luck figuring out which function returns the data-eid.  I'm hoping someone else has, or that there is a better way to get this info.  To be clear, I know how to use the Google Calendar API to get a list of events, and what I'm trying to do is tie those events to their corresponding event blocks on the Google Calendar page, which appear to only have unique class names that don't directly correlate to the underlying event ID.

Comment: seems like a job for a web crawler? havent tried implementing it tho.